# How can we wait for HttpURLConnection finish

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to make a Web connector class.

I never want this class have set text to view controller.

I want this class just try request to web then return string.

MyTest.java

```
public class MyTest {

    private String sUrl = "http://Secret";
    public String sRequestMethod;

    public String sResult;

    public String GetWebApi(final BaseRequest oRequest)
    {
      new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          try {
            URL url = new URL(sUrl);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod(oRequest.GetHttpMethod());
            String str = InputStreamToString(con.getInputStream());

          } catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
          }
        }
      }).start();

      return sResult;
    }

    private String InputStreamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException {
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      String line;
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
      }
      br.close();

      sResult = sb.toString();

      return sb.toString();
    }
  }
```

Home.java

```
public class Home extends Fragment {

      public Home() {
        // Required empty public constructor
      }

      @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
      }


      @Override
      public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        Button btn = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
            LoginRequest oLoginRequest = new LoginRequest();
            MyTest tt = new MyTest();
            TextView tv = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tv);
            tv.setText(tt.GetWebApi(oLoginRequest));
          }
        });
      }
}
```

To get response with HttpUrlConnection is successful.

But this program don't wait for finish GetWebApi method.

It just call GetWebApi -> do tv.setText(), So null set to tv.

Have you any idea. Thank you.

Comment: You can use a broadcast receiver to call a runnable or another thread that calls runOnUIThread to set the textview

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that is to replace the `Thread` in your `MyTest` class with an [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

This will take care of the coordination between making the request in the background and waiting for the result, so you can update the UI.

Simply move the logic to execute your request and parse the result to `doInBackground()` and then update your UI in `onPostExecute()`.

Answer (score 0):

Since I would want to run the network stuff asynchronously, this is how I would want to write the GetWebApi method:

```
public void GetWebApi(final BaseRequest oRequest)
    {
      new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          try {
            URL url = new URL(sUrl);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod(oRequest.GetHttpMethod());
            String str = InputStreamToString(con.getInputStream());
            Intent in = new Intent(Constants.NETWORK_RESULT);
            in.putExtra(Constants.VALUE, str);
            getContext().sendBroadcast(in);
          } catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
          }
        }
      }).start();

}
```

Now to receive the results  of the request;

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getStringExtra(Constants.VALUE)!=null) {
                tv.setText(intent.getStringExtra(Constants.VALUE))            }
        }
    };
```

Then register the receiver in the onStart method:

```
registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(Constants.NETWORK_RESULT));
```

This can also be done in an AsyncTask, that is if you won't mind.